# Angular2 importing component methods into another component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, auth0

I have a home component which needs to call LoginComponent method isLoggedIn() to check if the user is logged in as follows in @CanActivate

The home component should activate only if the user is logged in and authenticated

HomeComponent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {AboutComponent} from "../about/AboutComponent";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";

import {LoginComponent} from '../login/LoginComponent'

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
/*    template: `
    <div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" #name>
    </div>
    <button (click)="onGetAll(name.value)">GET Request
    </button>
    <p>Response: {{response}}</p>
    </div>
    <a [routerLink]="['../About']">link to About component</a>
    `,*/
    templateUrl: '../app/templates/dashboard.html',
    styleUrls: ['../app/assets/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css','../app/assets/demo.css','../app/assets/pe-icon-7-stroke.    css','../app/assets/bootstrap.min.css'],
    directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@CanActivate(() => LoginComponent.loggedIn())  //<-- This is not working 
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    response: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    onGetAll(name: string){
       console.log("Button clicked.. more code goes here " + name);  
    }
}
```

LoginCompoent.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {AuthHttp,AuthConfig, tokenNotExpired, AUTH_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-jwt';

import {HomeComponent} from '../home/HomeComponent'
import {AboutComponent} from '../about/AboutComponent'
import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'

declare var Auth0Lock;


@Component({
    selector: 'protected',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,AuthService]
})

export class LoginComponent { 

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
      this.auth.login();
  }
  login() {
     this.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

}
```

Comment: Add AuthService as provider in parent Component of Login and Home component. Usually App component. Remove it from Login. Now inject it in both home and login component and check whatever you need. Only one copy will be created for Auth Service since you provided it only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loggedIn` method is not a `static` method hence it will not be called,

Having said that, ideally, to check whether the **user logged-in** state you should call a service.

The service should tell if the user is logged-in and also it should have a static method on the service.

Comment: Yes, I have a service AuthService. it's imported into LoginComponent

Comment: Can you make loggedin a static method and try? and what is tokennotexpired method which is returned is it some method coming from auth0?

Comment: Thanks it worked. tokenexpired() is a boolean coming from Auth0.